# Can attack to a website from a parked subdomain with different hosts?

Tags: sql-injection, web-hosting, sub-domain

I have a website like `maindomain.com` that is hosted on one IP address like `192.168.1.1`. I want to add a subdomain from a different host (such as `192.168.1.2`) to my root domain (`maindomain.com`), such that the address will be like `subdomain.mainwebhost.com`.

If the subdomain host has a script with a security bug, can an actor attack the data hosted on my main host?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of SQL injection, if both domains are run by the same web server and an attacker is able to perform SQL injection on your subdomain host such that he/she can obtain information from the database, there is a good chance the attacker can also obtain information from your main host as well since both hosts use the same database and web server.